# data: images are not getting render. angular-cli aot build

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, firefox-os

I am developing a firefox os app and I am using  angular2 for it. 
In app, there are some images which path is mentioned in CSS file and after building angular-cli project in AOT mode 
`ng build --aot`
using this command I am not able to render that images data: image is formed in bundle but its not getting rendered.
I have also added CSP but still the same issue.

Does any one know how to solve that problem?

```
background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADsAAAL5CAYAAAAOmlw
 lAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAA3Z--some base 64 code for image--
-pVFh0WE1MOmNvbS5hZG9iZS54bXAAAAAAADw/eHBhY2tldCBiZWdpbj0i77u) 3px -480px no-repeat;
```

This is the image in base64 after bundle.